# Include full words in string slicing

Tags: python, string, loops

here's some code i have:

```
def breakUp(x,chunk_size):
    return [ x[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(x), chunk_size) ]
```

here's how it works:

```
In [8]: breakUp('This is a cool sentence... How about eating it??? Whats more?? pepper is available all for free!!!',10)

Out[8]: 
['This is a ',
 'cool sente',
 'nce... How',
 ' about eat',
 'ing it??? ',
 'Whats more',
 '?? pepper ',
 'is availab',
 'le all for',
 ' free!!!']
```

but as you see in the second element the word sentence is not taken completely, it says "sente"...

I know that this is because i've asked python to split it afer every 10 characters... is there anyway of specifying that i want to split after every 10 characters but if the 10th char. ends in a word, take the whole word...?

Comment: This sounds like homework, but I would split the line up into words (defined as letters separated by space) and then add words and space until I am >= chunk_size.

Comment: no but i want the chunk to be *x* **characters** long... i know that the mentioned constraint will cause the half-words. but what i now want is the chunk should be approx. *x* **characters** long. i can afford moving some characters the either side to engulf the word that is not fitting

Comment: Then figure out how much fuzziness you can allow as a number, add together the words to a string and then check the `len` and see if it falls within your +-`chunk_size`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Batteries included:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> print textwrap.fill('This is a cool sentence... How about eating it??? Whats more?? pepper is available all for free!!!', 15)
This is a cool
sentence... How
about eating
it??? Whats
more?? pepper
is available
all for free!!!
```

This does almost all you have asked for.  Except that if you specify `10` as a second parameter, it will still split `sentence...` since there is no way to fit it in 10 characters.  However, if you want to do this, you can customize `textwrap` with `break_long_words=False`:

```
>>> print textwrap.fill('This is a cool sentence... How about eating it??? Whats more?? pepper is available all for free!!!', 10, break_long_words=False)
This is a
cool
sentence...
How about
eating
it???
Whats
more??
pepper is
available
all for
free!!!
```

Comment: man, you solved my problem...!! except that `print textwrap.fill('This is a cool sentence... How about eating it??? Whats more?? pepper is available all for free!!!', 15).split('\n')` would give me what i want..!! now edit you answer for an accept!!!

Comment: @tenstar I used `textwrap.fill` for the demo.  If you don't need newlines, just use `textwrap.wrap` - see the doc http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html